# Why is the derivative at a jump undefined even if the slope remains the same?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definition

I've searched online and found almost nothing. What in the mathematical definition of a derivative makes it so that the derivative of the following is undefined at `0`.

\begin{equation*}
f(x) =\begin{cases}
3x  & \text{if } x < 0 \\
3x+2  & \text{if } x \ge 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Who says it's undefined at 0?  (This is a serious question, not rhetorical.)

Comment: @MJD My textbook.

Comment: The left limit $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0^{-}}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0^{-}}\frac{3h-2}{h}=+\infty$$

Comment: Although the derivative in 0 does not exist, the left derivative and right derivative in 0 do (and are equal). In fact we are dealing with a simple example of a function of bounded variation. Such functions have many special properties, see Rudin's book on analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my intuitive argument for why your book says what it does:

I personally consider the derivative as the best linear approximation of a function at some given point. For this function, at $x=0$ there isn't any good sort of linear approximation so we cannot have such a derivative.

As for a more proofy argument consider the limit
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$$
which I'm sure you recognize as the derivative. Now note that we must have this limit exist no matter how we approach it, i.e. if $h \in \mathbb{R}^-$ or $h \in \mathbb{R}^+$ or some combination of those two statements. Let's first consider when $h$ is negative and try to evaluate what $f'(0)$ is:
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{3h - 2}{h} = + \infty 
$$
so you can see that this does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

A function is continuous at a point if it is differentiable at it. But here you have a piecewise function, that is discontinuous at $0.$

Answer (score 0):

Recall the following definition of a derivative:
$$f'(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\text{.}$$
This limit exists if and only if the two-sided limits exist and 
$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0^{-}}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\text{.}$$

**Edit**: My attempt of computing the limits:
$$\begin{align}
&\lim\limits_{h \to 0^{-}}\dfrac{3(0+h)- 3(0) - 2}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^{-}}\dfrac{3h-2}{h} = +\infty\\
&\lim\limits_{h \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{3(0+h)+2-3(0)-2}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^{+}}3 = 3\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Comment: But don't those two limits `0-` and `0+` evaluate to the same thing since the +2 cancels out?

Comment: Hmm. Good point. Maybe my alternative argument is correct?

Comment: In your case $ \lim\limits_{h \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ = $ \lim\limits_{h \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{2-0}{h}$ which is infinite .

Comment: I think I figured it out. What I just said is wrong; it doesn't cancel out. From the positive side, the limit uses the function f(x) = 3x+2 and f(x+h) = 3(x+h) + 2, but from the negative side it uses f(x) = 3x and f(x+h) = 3(x+h) **+2**. That +2 doesn't cancel.

Comment: @TomCollinge how do you figure that? The right handed limit is
$$
\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{3x + 3h + 2 - 3x - 2}{h} = 3
$$
I believe the left hand sided limit is where problems arise.

Comment: Note that $f(0) = 3(0) + 2$. I.e. your first limit says $f(0) = 3(0)$ when by the definition of the function it should be $3(0) + 2$

Comment: @DanZimm That's what I was trying to get at in my comment.

Comment: Oh, now I see! Thank you @DanZimm!

Comment: @DanZimm True, I was a bit quick off the mark there.

Comment: I don't think the alternative explanation works. My guess is that the proof of it uses the fact (directly or indirectly) that jumps are not differentiable.

Comment: @MikeG I hadn't even seen your comment, my apologies but very good point!

Comment: @MikeG No, it doesn't. I remember reading from Bartle and Sherbert (now that I recall) that such an argument would only be valid for neighborhoods/intervals, rather than single points.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you should always note is that if $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=a$ then $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$. Thus this means if it is not continous at $x=0$ it can't be differentiable at that point either.